# Animsition: Delay between fade elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I am using [Animisation](https://github.com/blivesta/animsition) to make animations on website. I would like to show up elements in various delays.

e.g.:

```
element1 - starts at 0ms
element2 - starts at 1000ms
```

My code:

```
<div class="animsition element1">one</div>
<div class="animsition element2">two</div>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var $animsition = $('.animsition');
    $animsition.animsition();
  });
</script>
```

As you see I have `$animsition.animsition();` which activate animisition for each element with `animisition` class.

How can I easly define these delays for each of the elements?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have that solution:

```
  <div class="animsition one" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-left-lg">
    one
  </div>

  <div class="animsition two" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-right-lg">
    two
  </div>

  <div class="animsition three" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-left-lg">
    three
  </div>

  <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.one').animsition({onLoadEvent: false, timeout: true, timeoutCountdown: 500});
        $('.two').animsition({onLoadEvent: false, timeout: true, timeoutCountdown: 1000});
        $('.three').animsition({onLoadEvent: false, timeout: true, timeoutCountdown: 1500});
      });
  </script>
```

I can define animation type inline for each element. But it isn't that I am looking for. I must call `animsition()` function with atributes for each element - that isn't comfortable.

I prefer only once call `animsition()` function (it will be work for each element with class `animsition`) and operate on arguments.

Answer (score -1):

```
<animation 1>.delay(1000).<animation 2>
```

Comment: I have common animation activator for every elements. I don't define different animation for each. How can I implement delay in this case?
Additionally solution: `$('.one').animsition();
    $('.two').animsition().delay(200000);` doesnt work.